# Is there any way to define customized BERT MLM task?

Tags: nlp, bert-language-model

Now I want to use my own domain data to train BERT from scratch. The average length of my data is 4.5, which means that most of the length are around 3 to 5. If I apply the default model from huggingface, the MLM task would be quite difficult for the model to do since the data is too short to get a good infos from the context.

So I wonder if there is any way to modify the default MLM task? Or is there any way to change the mask algorithm?

Comment: 4.5 what? Words? Tokens? Anyway, with the HF library, you can change the % of masked tokens. Default is 15%, if I remember correctly

Comment: @SilentCloud 4.5 Tokens. That's quite short. I'll try to change the parameter. Thanks!!